# Can we Enable Send Log Per Business Unit in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-email

As per below Marketing Cloud documentation, Does it mean that we can have only one Send Log in an account?

"To use send logging, create a data extension using the send logging template. Each account can use one template and data extension for email messages and one template and data extension for SMS messages."

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 types of Send Logs Available in Marketing Cloud.

1. **Account Level Send Log** (AKA Enterprise Send Log) - This is enabled for an account and all sends (even from child Business units) will be logged under Enterprise Send Log.
2. **BU Level Send Log** - This can be enabled for a particular Business Uit (Child BU) and all the email sends from the child BU will be logged in the BU Level Send Log.

When you log a case with SFMC support, Make sure you specify which type of send log you want to enable and then create your send log template.

Comment: Can you source this with some documentation?  I'm not doubting, just curious (and interested in all SFMC things undocumented).

Comment: Because there is no documentation around this, I posted this here as a Q&A:).  I have done this for multiple clients and thought will share the knowledge with wider group.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Now I see you're answering your own question. Thanks for doing that.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I know this post is pretty old already and I cannot see anything in the documentation as well, but it is mentioned in a Trailhead module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-data-management/collect-data-with-a-send-log